# Using ActiveRecord serialize with Hash not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, serialization, activerecord

I've been reading up on the use of serialize from ActiveRecord, and I thought I understood how to use it, but my attempts are failing so I'm not sure if what I want is even possible this way? What I want is to store a simple hash linking id's of objects called accruals to a number of days. For example {"1" => "12", "5" => "24"}. I set this up as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      serialize :accrual_days, Hash
end
```

And for the database

```
def self.up
    unless column_exists? :users, :accrual_days
        add_column :users, :accrual_days, :text
    end
end
```

I then went into the rails console, and inputted these commands:

> User.find(1).accrual_days
>
> => nil
>
> User.find(1).accrual_days = {"1"=>"12"}
>
> => {"1"=>"12"}
>
> User.find(1).accrual_days
>
> => nil

It seems like the accrual_days are being set, but then it doesn't persist. I tried saving the user after setting the accrual day, and storing it as string instead of text in the database, but the problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not saving the values in the database.

Try

```
user = User.find(1)

user.accrual_days = {"1"=>"12"}

user.save

User.find(1).accrual_days
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I posted this a long time ago but better to accept an answer late than never!